# In drupal how to create lightbox or colorbox

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am working on drupal site & I want something like lightbox or colorbox which contains two buttons on it, first is "Enter Here" and another one is "Exit". And after user enters the site url, he will get this lightbox & all. And clicking on the first button user should go to the website & on clicking exit user should directed t google home page. And I am stuck on this. Please help me out...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to google it before posting in here ?

Comment: Yeah. But m not getting it. And I want to use it for the dating site so that I can restrict the viewers of the sites.

Comment: http://d3pr5r64n04s3o.cloudfront.net/tuts/316_modal/final.png Please see this. I want something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need of this module . Below is the link

[click here](http://drupal.org/project/disclaimer)

So you need to install (v7) the `colorbox` module too to make it work . [here](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) is the link

**Here are the steps**

---

In order to work, disclaimer need client has **JAVASCRIPT ENABLED and ACCEPT COOKIE**.

**NOTICE ON AGE VERIFICATION:**

If you set age form option to your disclaimer, delete cookie and see the modal from
"`admin/config/system/disclaimer`", age verification will not work, because javascript is not
loaded on admin pages.

---

### Requirements

This module require at least version 7.x of Drupal.
This module require colorbox module 7.x-2.0+

### Installation

1. Copy the folder named '`disclaimer`' and its contents to the modules directory
   of your Drupal installation (for example 'sites/all/modules/').
2. Go to '`admin/build/modules`' and enable disclaimer.
3. Go to '`admin/config/system/disclaimer`' and edit option and content for the disclaimer
   to your need.

### Test

You can use firefox/firebug to see and delete cookie "`disclaimerShow`".

---

Comment: Hey I have installed it. But it shows me this: "Disclaimer 7.x-1.x-dev A colorbox disclaimer to add splash on your website.
Requires: Colorbox (missing)" Why it show that colobox missing msg?

Comment: @vickram http://drupal.org/project/colorbox install this also. it is needed by that disclaimer module

Comment: Hey Deonia, the module is successfully installed. But it is not displaying on any page. Can u tell me where i am getting  wrong?

Comment: what is the error you are getting . have you done initial setup and setting  of the module. Read above the installation steps

Comment: The problem is I am not getting any error and success also. I have done the setting for the disclaimer module. But nothing is displaying on the site and on any page.